# Make `burn` and `burnBatch` to be callable only by the smart contract

Tags: solidity

currently i'm working on NFT collection using `ERC1155, ERC1155Burnable` standards from `OpenZeppelin`. I'm trying to override access to `burn` and `burnBatch` functions, by default is public when we inherit `ERC1155Burnable`, any idea how to make them callable only by the smart contract that inherits `ERC1155Burnable` or in other words `private`?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you inheriting `ERC1155Burnable`, then? `_burn` and `_burnBatch` exist and are private in `ERC1155`, the only thing the Burnable extension does is exposing them in public methods.